# Не могу реализовать бинарный поиск для игры

Tags: javascript, search, binary

Всем привет, не могу реализовать бинарный поиск для небольшой игры в угадай число)

дело в том что когда я нажимаю кнопку больше прибавляется половина от изначального числа ,а когда нажимаю меньше вычитает половину из уже прибавленного числа , а мне нужно чтобы он вычитал из промежутка между начальным числом и которое уже прибавленное и так же с кнопкой меньше) помогите кто может

вот пример, запустите и попробуйте

```js
window.onload = function(){
                
                var wrapInner = document.querySelector('.wrap__inner');
                var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
                var q = document.querySelector('.q');
                var big = document.createElement('h3');
                var small = document.createElement('h3');
                
                
                var res = 50;
    
                btn.onclick = function(){
                    q.innerHTML = res;

                    this.style.display = 'none';

                    big.classList.add('big');
                    big.innerHTML = 'Больше';
    
                    small.classList.add('small');
                    small.innerHTML = 'Меньше';
                    
                    wrapInner.appendChild(big);
                    wrapInner.appendChild(small);                   
                }
                small.onclick = function(){
                    
                    var middle = search(Number(q.innerHTML),0);
                    q.innerHTML = middle;
                    if(q.innerHTML > middle){
                        search(middle,0);
                    }
                }

                big.onclick = function(){
                    var middle = search(Number(q.innerHTML),100);
                    q.innerHTML = middle;
                    
                    
                }
                function search(start,end,middle){
                    middle = Math.floor((start + (end - start)/2));
                    return middle;
                }
            }
```

```css
.wrap{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .btn{
            background: black;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .wrap__inner{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .big{
            background: black;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .small{
            background: black;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
        <h1>Загадайте число от 0 до 100 и нажмите на кнопку!</h1>
        <div class="btn">Нажимай!</div>
        <hr>
        <h2 class="q"></h2>
        <div class="wrap__inner"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного поменял ваш код...

• Если несколько элементов принимают одинаковый стиль, их можно записать через запятые, не повторяя одно и то же несколько раз.

• Если что-то легко делается через HTML или CSS, то и скрипт тогда не нужен. В данном случае можно было изначально в HTML записать кнопки "больше" и "меньше" и просто делать их скрытыми изначально. Через скрипт только показать.

• Надо было додуматься только до того, чтобы сделать 2 переменных, куда будут хранится верхний и нижний пределы. Если тыкнута кнопка "меньше" - текущее число сохраняяем как верхний предел. А если "выше" - наоборот, в переменную "high"

• с элементами  очень неудобно работать там, где они не являются именно заглавлением... заменил на другие.

• События типа `onclick` "за кадром" создают штуку, которая может принимать только одно значение. Т.е. если еще где-то в коде захочется привязать к этому же элементу onclick - новый добавленный перепишет старое значение и старый клик не будет работать. А `window.onload` в данном случае можно заменить на `(function(){ ... })();` — Функция с такими скобками будет работать сразу при загрузке. И таких можно добавить много... когда onload будет только один.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/qh1xfr2m/)

```js
(function(){
  var btn   = document.getElementById('btn');
  var q     = document.getElementById('q');
  var small = document.getElementById('small');
  var big   = document.getElementById('big');
  var res = Math.floor( Math.random()*101 );

  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    q.innerText = res;
    this.classList.add('invis');
    small.parentNode.classList.remove('invis');
  });
  
  var low  = 0;
  var high = 101;
  function search(){return Math.floor( (low + high)/2 );}
  
  small.addEventListener('click', function(){
    high = Number(q.innerText);
    q.innerText = search();    
  });
  
  big.addEventListener('click', function(){
    low = Number(q.innerText);    
    q.innerText = search();   
  });
  
})();
```

```css
#btn, #big, #small {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn {margin: auto;} /*Центрирование*/
.center {text-align: center;}
.h2 {font-size: 22px;} .h1 {font-size: 28px;}
.invis {display: none;} /*Невидимка*/
```

```html
<div class="center h1">Загадайте число от 0 до 100 и нажмите на кнопку!</div>
<div id="btn">Нажимай!</div>
<div id="q" class="center h1"></div>
<div class="invis center">
  <button id="small">Меньше</button><button id="big">Больше</button>
</div>
```

Но так не интересно. Можно было не среднее значение считать каждый раз, а выводить рандомное число из этого интервала. Это будет выглядеть так:

```
return: Math.floor( Math.random()*(high - low) + low);
```

Math.random() создает случайное число от 0 [включительно] до 1 (не включительно). Созданным числом потом можно манипулировать, чтобы получить нужное нам) Скажем, если нужно число между 100 (high) и 40 (low), умножая на (100-40) получаем случайное число от 0 до 60. Прибавляем low, получается от 40 до 100.